# example path but not connected

Tags: general-topology

In my course notes of topology, we have seen the following example of a space that is connected but not path-connected.

Define $X := \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x,\sin(\frac{1}{x}))\mid  x > 0\}$

I understand why this is connected but I have troubles by arguing why it's not path-connected.
my opinion: consider $X$ is path-connected

- for $x = (0,0)$ and $y = (1,\sin(1))$ , there is a continuous function $f\colon [0,1] \rightarrow X: 0 \mapsto x, 1 \mapsto y$
- because $[0,1]$ is compact and $f$ is continuous, $X$ is compact. I think that $X$ is not compact but I can't prove why. If I can prove this, $f$ can't be continuous and then it's ok.

Comment: It's not $X$ that is compact, but the trace of the path, $f([0,\,1])$. If the path existed, that would contain $Y = \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x,\sin (1/x)) : 0 < x \leqslant 1\}$, which then would also be compact.